# Kentico 11: using variables inside text/xml transformations

Tags: transformation, web-parts, kentico-11

I'm working on a carousel webpart with a text/xml transformation.
Simply trying to create a unique ID for each instance on the page.
Next I'd like to have the first item set to active with a CSS class.

---

For the section **Webpart container**:

```
{% uniqueId = string.FormatString("carousel-{0}", InstanceGuid.Substring(0,5)); #%}
<div id="{%uniqueId%}" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    □
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#{%uniqueId%}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#{%uniqueId%}" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

This seems to work at first but for some reason it generates a text-node in HTML.
**How can we do this without generating the variable output?**

---

For a single carousel item in the **Transformations** section:

```
{% CssActive = IsFirst() ? "active" : string.Empty %}
<div class="carousel-item {%CssActive%}">
    <img src="{%Image%}" alt="" class="w-100 d-block" />
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>{%Title%}</h3>
        <div>{%Body%}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

This doesn't output anything? Is this even possible to use `IsFirst()` in a repeater?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the transformation you can use the following code:

```
<div class="carousel-item{% if (DataItemIndex == 0) { " active" } #%}">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="{%Image%}" alt="" class="card-img-top" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="card-title">{%Title%}</h3>
      <div class="card-text">{%Body%}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Doc](https://docs.xperience.io/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods)

Answer (score 1):

For the Webpart container I can do a workaround with HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="d-none">
{% uniqueId = string.FormatString("carousel-{0}", InstanceGuid.Substring(0,5)); #%}
</div>
```

Far from ideal so if anybody else has a better idea ...?